# Experience Bundle Migration Error: [NavigationMenu Admins] No page found in the site for Menu Item URL path "/application-list"

Tags: community, migration, experience-bundle

We are trying to deploy experience bundle from sandbox to production with Copado but we are getting below error -

[NavigationMenu Admins] No page found in the site for Menu Item URL path "/application-list". Please ensure the page for Menu Item "Applications" exists in your site and follows proper formatting: begins with a / character, and consists only of characters that are permitted in a URL path for Menu Item Type "Internal"

We have checked the page which is being called on click of navigation menu is present in the package.
Dependent components added on the page are part of the package

We have observed that production have API ver 56.0 and sandbox has 57.0 Is that a problem?

From sandbox to sandbox, same package worked well and did not throw any error. Does anyone have any clue on this? your help will be much appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this error?